# Is flashback usage limited?

Tags: grid-2

I can use flashback, and go back in time, by pressing my <kbd>←</kbd> (backspace) key. However, I lost the ability to do so in middle of a race after I had used it quite a few times.

Am I only allowed to use it for a limited amount of times per race, or was it some other issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, the number of flashbacks is limited.

The number of flashbacks you have available differs depending on difficulty, and is shown in the bottom left of the screen, next to the mini map;

[image]